# Bordeless editor maui UITextView Does not contain a definition for BorderStyle

Tags: maui

I am trying to remove the underline in the editor but I keep getting " UITextView Does not contain a definition for BorderStyle" Android is fine but iOS is complaining

```
public class BorderlessEditor : Editor
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EditorHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("BorderlessEditor", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is BorderlessEditor)
            {
#if __ANDROID__
                    handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif __IOS__
                    if (handler.NativeView is UIKit.UITextView textView)
                    {
                        textView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
                        textView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
                    }
#endif
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```xml
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EditorHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Borderless", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is Editor)
            {
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.Background = null;     
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
                handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
                handler.PlatformView.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
#endif
            }
        });
```